# Mono.Addins: Can a main app register an extension whose extension point is registered by another app?

Tags: mono.addins

I have the following scenario:

**Common Project**

- Registers a few extension points (all interfaces) Have a public
  Extension manager class which gives back registered extensions

**Library Project**

- Registered as addin root Registers an extension whose extension point
  is registered by Common Project Registers an extension point
- Has an extension manager which gives back extensions registered to the
  extension point above
- Queries Common project to retrieve extension of one type and gets nothing (Extension is registered by main app, haven't tried putting a copy of exe in addins directory)

**Main Application (exe)**

- Registered ass addin root Registers an extension whose extension point is in Common Project
- Queries an extension where both extension point and extension are registered in Library Project.
- Succeeds to get extension only when Library.dll is in ./addins directory.

**My questions are**

1. Can't we have a separate project that only registers extension
   points and have other assemblies including the main app
   export/register extensions to those points?
2. Are we supposed to keep all extension points in Main application or
   some addin root? What if extension developers ship their extensions
   that reference outdated version of our main assemblies that register
   the points?

Comment: Tobia Zambon asks a similar question and Lluis Sanchez answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417219/mono-addin-implementation-doesnt-retrieve-addins